# One collection, two bindings

Tags: wpf

Is it possible to bind one ObservableCollection to two Listbox ItemsSource's in the same view?

```
public ObservableCollection<CameraListBoxItem> Window1CameraListBoxItems
{
    get { return cameraListBoxItems; }
}

<ListBox x:Name="DeviceList" ItemsSource="{Binding Window1CameraListBoxItems}" />
<ListBox x:Name="DeviceList2" ItemsSource="{Binding Window1CameraListBoxItems}" />
```

It doesn't seem to work and I don't understand why.

**UPDATE**

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:WindowViewModel}">
    <vw:WindowView />
</DataTemplate>
```

Using MVVM the view is binded to the viewmodel.

```
public WindowViewModel(ObservableCollection<CameraListBoxItem> items)
{
    cameraListBoxItems = items;
}
```

Comment: Did you set your DataContext?

Comment: The datacontext is set to the viewmodel which holds Window1CameraListBoxItems... the first listbox does contain the items.

Comment: Can we see the code for that bit, please?

Comment: I think your referring to the datacontext of the view.... I updated my question.

Comment: i think You haven't raise event like raisepropertychanged. you must have to write RaisepropertyChanged("propertyname") in your viewmodel.

Comment: Ah, yes... that makes more sense. I'll implement that. Thanks.

Comment: Wait, does it? I'm not exactly changing the collection... its set within the constructor... i'm only trying to get the collection.

Comment: Also, the property holding the collection does get hit twice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.  You can bind as many elements as you wish to the same source property.

I would check the bindings debugging information in the Output Window.  This may not be working because *both* bindings are incorrect, which could happen if the `DataContext` isn't set properly.

Comment: Not sure what changed... but messing with the viewmodel repeatably seemed to fix the issue.